# How can I implement the binomial transform?

Tags: difference-equations, sequence

How do I implement the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform)?

I've tried defining a matrix

```
P = Table[(-1)^k Binomial[n, k], {n, 0, m}, {k, 0, m}]
```

and having this act on my sequence (of length `m + 1`). But this seems quite crude. I shouldn't need to specify the length of my sequence.

Given the relationship to forward differences, can I implement it directly through `Differences`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sequence_transforms) has a link to this [file](https://oeis.org/seqtranslib.txt) which gives the following code:

```
(* Difference Table (Binomial)  Transforms *)

BinomialTransform[{},___]={};
BinomialTransform[seq_List,way_:1]:=Table[Sum[way^(i - 1 - k)*Binomial[i - 1, k]*seq[[k + 1]], {k, 0, i - 1}],{i,1,Length[seq]}];
BinomialInvTransform[{},___]={};
BinomialInvTransform[seq_List,way_:1]:=BinomialTransform[seq,-way]
```

(Note that this BinomialTransform is the inverse of the one defined in the question and in wikipedia.)

For example,

```
 x=Table[n(3^n-2^n),{n,0,4}];
 NestList[BinomialInvTransform,x,6]//TableForm
```

reproduces Jackson's difference fan of from page 86 of Conway and Guy's [Book of Numbers](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=0--3rcO7dMYC&pg=PA63&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false):

```
0 1 10 57 260
0 1 8 30 88
0 1 6 9 12
```

Comment: Sorry, to the other good answers, but I'm going to accept my own (taken from OEIS) as "canonical", ignoring elegance & efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

```
L = {a, b, c, d, e};
binT = NestList[Minus@*Differences, #, Length[#] - 1][[All, 1]] &;
binT[L]
```

> {a, a - b, a - 2 b + c, a - 3 b + 3 c - d, a - 4 b + 6 c - 4 d + e}

Or this (longer, but uses less memory)

```
binT = Reap[Nest[(Sow[First[#]]; #)& @* Minus @* Differences,
                 (Sow[First[#]]; #), Length[#] - 1]][[2, 1]] &;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f0, f1, f2, f3, f4]

f0[x_] := Module[{m = Length@x - 1}, Table[(-1)^k Binomial[n, k], {n, 0, m}, {k, 0, m}].x]
f1[x_] := Module[{r = Range[Length@x] - 1}, Outer[(-1)^#2 Binomial@## &, r , r].x]
f2[x_] := Module[{i = 0}, (-1)^(i++) Differences[x, #][[1]] & /@ Range[0, Length @ x- 1]]
f3[x_] := Module[{r = Range[Length@x] - 1}, (-1)^r (Differences[x, #][[1]] & /@ r)]
f4[x_] := MapIndexed[(-1)^(1 + #2[[1]]) Differences[x, #2[[1]] - 1][[1]] &, x]
```

Examples:

```
f0 @ {a, b, c, d, e}
```

> {a, a - b, a - 2 b + c, a - 3 b + 3 c - d, a - 4 b + 6 c - 4 d + e}

```
f0 @ Array[Subscript[y, #] &, {6}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Equal @@ (#@{a, b, c, d, e} & /@ {f0, f1, f2, f3, f4})
```

> True

```
Equal @@ (#@Array[Subscript[y, #] &, {6}] & /@ {f0, f1, f2, f3, f4})
```

> True